# Free way to get financial data as Bloomberg terminal

Tags: programming, application, finance

I was wondering if there are some free ways (applications or programming) to get financial data (either live data, historical data or both), achieving similar function as Bloomberg terminal?

Comment: There is e.g. the 'Yahoo Finance API', see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763310/yahoo-finance-api

Comment: I think this question should be migrated somewhere else such as http://quant.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ...do not use marketing terms such as `bloomberg terminal`. Besides that please review this thread [here](http://quant.stackexchange.com/search?q=quantmod) and then ask a question. Yahoo API is trivial, there are packages that handles many APIs! For example, fire up R and `library(quantmod); getSymbols("VT"); plot(VT)` and you get VT -- but this question is AGAIN-AGAIN asked in quant.SE and money.SE. Unless this term `bloomberg termial` specified, this question has no value. What the heck this has to do with Unix now? Nothing, dot. -1 until clarified or moved to other site.

Comment: Clutter [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754593/source-of-historical-stock-data), more clutter [here](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/9655/data-source-for-historical-intra-day-bid-ask-price-data-for-stocks), less clutter [here](http://quant.stackexchange.com/search?q=quantmod) (repetition) -- and finally read this [here](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/7926/who-owns-historical-valuations-about-equity-such-as-stocks-and-index-funds) (a small warning for this euphoria). There is nothing special really with `financial data`, detailed data is expensive and restrictive.

Comment: I think someone should categorize this mess over SE with financial stuff, it is at the best repetitive (often with flashy new news to make a slight variation but eventually not much difference) -- bad like hxll! I like d this [here](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1339/how-random-are-financial-data-series), perhaps Quant.SE or Money.SE should have some newbie/ignorant question aggregator for similar qs?

Comment: I was going to try migrating this, but it's duplicated in enough places that I'll just close it

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: Thank you. Until well specified, this kind of questions should be closed immediately. Populistic things such as `Bloomberg terminal` are all the time changing, making threads become rotten soon. Besides not anything to do with *ix here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andre Holzner suggested, I would suggest using the Yahoo Finance API.  It's what I used for this problem set: http://cdn.cs75.net/2010/fall/projects/2/project2.pdf

Comment: Hello, R's quantmod has Yahoo API inside and much more, look this [here](http://quant.stackexchange.com/search?q=quantmod). Research a bit and do not recommend the first google things. Also a reference to W3.* is not very convincing, diversion perhaps this helps [here](http://w3fools.com/). -1 because nothing to do with Unix and uneducated response. You may want to trial with R like this `library(quantmod); getSymbols("VT"); plot(VT)`. It is a wrapper but it has much more to offer to build this kind of `financila terminals`, not just one API.